# Setting Minimum Width with @media

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to back into some css located here (https://github.com/rothkj1022/phppickem/blob/master/css/bootstrap.min.css).

How can I use @media to say after 480px, stop resizing?  The columns get too cluttered at smaller resolutions and I would like to just keep it as is.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to resize from **1px** to **480px** you should say:

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 480px ){

}
```

In the other case you want to resize from **480px** to **infinite** you should use this:

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 480px ){

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop CSS call more than **480px** then you should use this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){

  /* write css here */
}
```

It works for less than **480px**.